# Keyboard issue in iOS 8 on iPAD mini

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8, ipad-mini

Few of our Customers are reporting keyboard is zooming out in my app and they were not able to minimize it. They were reported this issue is happening only in my app.

We haven't done any keyboard customization in our app.

Accessibility features is turned off on customer iPAD's.

Device model: iPad 2,7

OS : iOS 8.4

We are not able to reproduce the issue.

Let me know if anyone knows the solution for the problem.
[image: Keyboard zoomed out]

Comment: It looks like the landscape keyboard is being used in portrait mode which is something that hasn't been fixed since iOS 7 (not even in iOS 9 betas). Unless you're doing some crazy rotation hacks, I'm afraid this is not something you can fix yourself.

Comment: Thank you for quick response Filip :) . Another strange issue reported by customers is they are able to see keyboard if they change it to landscape mode but not able to press any keys.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off predictions in settings fixed this issue.